# How to specify the default value for a vector argument with Clap 4

Tags: rust, clap

I have the following type:

```rust
#[derive(clap::ValueEnum, Clone, Debug)]
pub enum Processor {
    DefaultProcessor,
    SecondaryProcessor,
}
```

I have a FromStr impl for this struct as well (not shown because it's very simple).

I am currently using this in a struct like this:

```rust
#[derive(Parser)]
pub struct RunLocalTestnet {
    /// Processors to run.
    #[clap(long)]
    processors: Vec<Processor>,
}
```

So far so good, this works great. What I'm trying to do now is add a default value for this vector, for example:

```rust
    #[clap(long, default_value_t = vec![Processor::DefaultProcessor])]
    processors: Vec<Processor>,
```

Unfortunately when I do this I get the following error:

```
error[E0277]: `Vec<processor::processors::Processor>` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
   --> crates/aptos/src/node/local_testnet.rs:103:18
    |
103 |     #[clap(long, default_value_t = vec![Processor::DefaultProcessor])]
    |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `Vec<processor::processors::Processor>` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
    |
    = help: the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `Vec<processor::processors::Processor>`
    = note: in format strings you may be able to use `{:?}` (or {:#?} for pretty-print) instead
    = note: required for `Vec<processor::processors::Processor>` to implement `ToString`
```

Is there a way to make this work with Clap 4 (specifically 4.3.9) out of the box? I feel like it shouldn't be necessary to make `Processor` impl `Display` because it works up until I set the default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want `default_values_t` (note the `s`). `default_value_t` requires the type to implement `Display` or `ValueEnum` which of course `Vec<T>` does not. But `default_values_t` requires the type to be a `Vec<T>` where only `T` has to implement `Display` or `ValueEnum`, which is exactly what you have.

Docs page: https://docs.rs/clap/4.3.9/clap/_derive/index.html

- `default_value = <str>`: [`Arg::default_value`](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/struct.Arg.html#method.default_value) and [`Arg::required(false)`](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/struct.Arg.html#method.required)
- `default_value_t [= <expr>]`: [`Arg::default_value`](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/struct.Arg.html#method.default_value) and [`Arg::required(false)`](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/struct.Arg.html#method.required)

  - Requires `std::fmt::Display` that roundtrips correctly with the [`Arg::value_parser`](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/struct.Arg.html#method.value_parser) or `#[arg(value_enum)]`
  - Without `<expr>`, relies on `Default::default()`
- `default_values_t = <expr>`: [`Arg::default_values`](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/struct.Arg.html#method.default_values) and [`Arg::required(false)`](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/struct.Arg.html#method.required)

  - Requires field arg to be of type `Vec<T>` and `T` to implement `std::fmt::Display` or `#[arg(value_enum)]`
  - `<expr>` must implement `IntoIterator<T>`

Comment: More specifically OP wants `#[arg(long, value_enum, default_values_t = [Processor::DefaultProcessor])] processors: Vec<Processor>` (without `value_enum` it won't work either.

Comment: Great, that works! Indeed, including `value_enum` is necessary for it to work.